# Redirect http to https exclude specific IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-redirect

I have used the following rule to exclude 200.200.0.17 to be redirected from http to https, but its requests (from 200.200.0.17) are still being redirected to https. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
# If mod_rewrite is present, it takes precedence over mod_alias
# and it is necessary to rewrite the request to https.
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^200.200.0.17
     RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1
  </IfModule>

# Otherwise use mod_alias to redirect.
  Redirect / https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you Kanchan? Please accept it if it did using the tick at the top left of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first rule is executed, the second one is also executed. To prevent this from happening, use the `last` flag. Change the line in your code:

```
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1 [L]
```

See: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.htm

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have the alternative redirect set up, remove:

```
Redirect / https://%{HTTP_HOST}/
```

Or it will just keep redirecting that IP after the first rule ignores it.